# Iterating over object results in infinite loop

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, iterator, infinite-loop

I have an object that I am trying to recursively iterate over, but get stuck in an infinite loop. I suspect that the issue is that the variable `i` in my for loop does not increase, but why?

My code:

```
var failsafe = 0;
function iter(obj) {
    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        console.log("Now #"+i);
        if (typeof obj[i].contains == "object") {
            console.log(obj[i].command);
            iter(obj[i].contains);
        } else {
            console.log(obj[i].command);
        }
        if (failsafe==20) return false;
        failsafe++;
    }
}
iter(parsed);
```

Console input:

```
Now #0
do (5)
Now #0
move.up()
Now #1
move.left()
Now #2
if (check.up() == "item")
Now #0
move.down()
Now #2
if (check.up() == "item")
Now #0
move.down()
Now #2
if (check.up() == "item")
Now #0
move.down()
... and so on
```

Object:

```
[
    {
        "command":"do (5)",
        "contains":[
            {
                "command":"move.up()",
                "contains":false
            },
            {
                "command":"move.left()",
                "contains":false
            },
            {
                "command":"if (kind == \"item\")",
                "contains":[
                    {
                        "command":"move.down()",
                        "contains":false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "command":"move.right()",
                "contains":false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you never declare var i. So when you do for (i=0;...) the variable i is in fact attached to the window (you can easily check that by logging window.i).
The result is you use the same variable for all your loops and the problem is it restarts at 0 everytime!

Easy fix : for(var i = 0;...)